# Mule Java Component and Thread Safe

Tags: multithreading, mule

An excerpt from this http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Java+Components is:

`When you specify the class directly on the component or pooled-component element, the PrototypeObjectFactory is used by default, and a new instance is created for each invocation, or a new pooled component is created in the case of the PooledJavaComponent`

And, I have configured a Java class as Mule Java component like below:

`<component class="com.mycompany.SalesOrderProductsHandler" doc:name="Java" />`. The class `SalesOrderProductsHandler` has implemented `org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable` and has one state variable named **targetProductsIndex**.

My question follows:

Will a new instance of `com.mycompany.SalesOrderProductsHandler` get created every time a new request comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is absolutely correct. With:

```
<component class="com.mycompany.SalesOrderProductsHandler" />
```

you will get a new instance of `com.mycompany.SalesOrderProductsHandler` for each invocation.

Comment: Just to confirm: here each invocation means each incoming request, doesn't it? If this is correct, can I  have any state in my Java component with out worrying about thread-safe?

Comment: "each invocation means each incoming request" <- most probably yes, but maybe no if you use the `cache` scope, an `aggregrator` or other routing message processors... And yes, in this case your component can have state and not worry about thread safety.

Comment: Having curiosity, I just want to know that: what will happen if my component is in the `cache` scope? Is the component still thread-safe? Otherwise what I am supposed to do, is it sufficient to clear/reset the state after each invocation of the component i.e., to restore to defaults of the state variable just before returning `onCall()` method.

Comment: The best thing to do is to make your component stateless and never have to worry about thread safety. Restoring to a default value will not make it thread safe, removing all state would. The cache scope won't change the instantiation policy but it would affect the "one component invocation per incoming request" assumption, since not all incoming requests will hit the component.

Comment: Agreed of course. Though my Java component has state, it is thread-safe as along as it does not use `cache` scope, an `aggregator` or other routing message processors,like you mentioned. Can I take it for granted?

Comment: No, if it has mutable state it is not thread safe. My mention of `cache` _et al_ was regarding your question about whether one inbound request always results in one component invocation.

Comment: Okay. To conclude an answer to my question: There are no `cache` scope, an `aggregrator`or other routing messaged processors associated my Java component but having the **state**. As you mentioned in one of your comments, is it thread safe at least as long as the above statement holds good.